# Pipeline - Run a job if at least one previous job succeed

Tags: yaml, azure-pipelines, jobs

I have a list of jobs A, B, C, D... which run no matter if the previous job succeed.

The last of them is the artifact publish, that will be used by the Release pipeline. I would like to **not run** it **if none of the previous jobs succeed**.

I need to deploy any service which does not fail (so I need to pass the failed services creations) but prevent the automatic launch of the release pipeline linked if all failed.

[image: Pipeline]

Here is the YAML code given by Azure

```
pool:
  name: Default
  demands:
  - msbuild
  - visualstudio

steps:
- task: VSBuild@1
  displayName: 'Generate Solution'
  inputs:
    solution: LisaMES.sln
    platform: '$(PlatformName)'
    configuration: '$(ConfigurationName)'


- task: ArchiveFiles@2
  displayName: 'Create Service A'
  inputs:
    rootFolderOrFile: '$(ServiceName)\bin\$(ConfigurationName)'
    includeRootFolder: false
    archiveFile: 'Bin_Services/$(ServiceName)_$(ConfigurationName).zip'
  condition: succeededOrFailed()



- task: ArchiveFiles@2
  displayName: 'Create Service B'
  inputs:
    rootFolderOrFile: '$(ServiceName)\bin\$(ConfigurationName)'
    includeRootFolder: false
    archiveFile: 'Bin_Services/$(ServiceName)_$(ConfigurationName).zip'
  condition: succeededOrFailed()



 ... C D E F like this


- task: PublishPipelineArtifact@0
  displayName: 'Publish Pipeline Artifact'
  inputs:
    artifactName: Services
    targetPath: 'Bin_Services'
  condition: succeededOrFailed()
```

Comment: Can you provide your YAML code?  I am assuming the jobs are already set up to run in parallel?

Comment: No the jobs are not running in parallel. I can give the YAML code generated by Azure but i cannot edit it though

Answer (score -1):

remove the condition on the `PublishPipelineArtifact@0` As it currently reads this [task will run irregardless](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/conditions?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) if the preceding tasks succeeded or published.

```
Even if a previous dependency has failed, unless the run was canceled. Use succeededOrFailed() in the YAML for this condition.
```

Unless there is a reason you'd want to publish a subset of artifacts that succeeded (this could lead to an inconsistent build state as the same build could produce different artificats) would recommend removing the condition from all the tasks. The default behavior is to run each task only if the preceding task was successful.

Comment: I need the artifact for publishing my services in the release wich come next.

Comment: Wouldn't you need all the artifacts? If some of the artifacts are failing by design would suggest re evaluating how you are using pipelines. The pipeline should consistently produce the same number/type of artifacts based on input unless you are adding removing them.

Comment: I am producing one artifact containing a various number of files